# Printing n choose k combinations in matlab

Tags: matlab, combinations

I need to create an [algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pyvg2.png) in matlab which returns any combination of n subset from the k set. For example I have a set {1,2,3,4,5} and I need any combination of 3 numbers included in this set. So this function should returns:

**[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5], [3, 4, 5]]**

I have tried to write it by myself, but unsuccessfully and I give up. It partially works, but it creates endless loop.

```
for i=1:n
    if(firstTime)
        lastComb=min //123
        firstTime=false
    else
        for d=k:-1:1
            while(lastComb(:,end) < n-k+d && lastComb(:,end)<=n)
                newComb=lastComb
                newComb(d)=lastComb(d)+1
                combos= [combos; newComb]
                lastComb=newComb
            end
            while(lastComb(:,end) > n-k+d && lastComb(:,end)<=n)
                newComb=lastComb
                for p=d:-1:1

                    if(newComb(p)+1 <=n)
                        newComb(p)=newComb(p)+1
                        combos= [combos; newComb]
                    end
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: `//` is not valid MATLAB syntax. Are you sure you ran the code as it here? Also please include the initialization of your variables. You need to copy-paste complete code we can run. See [mre].

Comment: If all what you need is a function that does the job you can use: [`nchoosek`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html)

Comment: Did you try `nchoosek(1:5,3)`?

Answer (score 0):

Overall, your syntax is a little confusing (as previously stated by someone else). If you're posting a question here, it's a good idea to include all of your code, including the defined variables just for ease of those that are helping you.

A few major issues that I'm seeing with what you have are as follows:

(1) You seem to only be getting "n" combinations with what you're writing, which I think is 3 combinations. Instead, you should be getting 10 combinations. The beginning of this function should probably have a combination calculation [nCk = n!/((n-k)!*k!)].

(2) You're defining the first combination as 1,2,3, but then you don't but it into the "combos" set that you are making. Instead you replace it with something else before it can reach "combos."

There are a couple more, but try fixing these parts and the others may come naturally.

Overall, this function already exists. Just type "open nchoosek" into MATLAB to see a refined version of what you are attempting if you get stuck!